# Responsive css grid - how to make first item 2 x width and responsive

Tags: css, css-grid

I have made the following with CSS grid:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAtiA.jpg (animated gif showing current behaviour)

This the behaviour I want, except I want the first image to be 2 times the width (ie 3 cols with the first item spanning 2 cols, as in the mock below):

[image]

This is the code I have so far

```html
.news-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(441px, 1fr));
    margin-top:2rem;
    column-gap: 2.33em;
    row-gap:  2.33em;

}
.news-item:first-child {
    grid-column:  1 2;
  }

.news-item {
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 5px solid #fff;
color: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.112);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
```

}

Is it possble ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just the two photos, and you want the second one to wrap onto a new line when you shrink the screen, it's easier to use a flex box:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
}

.container div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font: 24px sans-serif;
}

.one {
  flex-basis: 441px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.two {
  flex-basis: 220px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

You can experiment with `flex-grow`, `flex-basis` and `max-width` if you don't want your second picture to take up the whole width when it bumps to the next line.

As far as I know, the only way to get this behavior with a grid, unless the cells are all the same size, is to use media queries and respecify the grid rectangle directly for the smaller screen.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - went with this approach in the end.

Comment: @Burns You're very welcome. If you find this to be the solution to your problem, please accept it (and upvote it) so others with the same problem will be able to find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

`grid-area` can do this. For example:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 2 / span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution won't drop the second element onto the next line when the screen size decreases.

Comment: Correct, and there are ways to deal with that.  My goal was just to help OP on the grid-area course.

Comment: What ways are there to deal with that using a grid, short of respecifying the grid area in media queries? There may be some, but I'm unaware of them.